# GeoTrust SSL error in Android

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have got GeoTrust certificate "GeoTrust SSL CA - G3" and every online SSL checker show me, that it's correctly installed, but when I use my site with Android older than version 4.4 I give bad error, why?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: What do you get from https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ in the "Handshake simulation" section for Android 4.4 browser? Please update your question with results.